# is it possible for selenium to validate XML elements based on Xpath

Tags: xml, selenium, xpath

my webpage generates an XML in the below format, can we able validate the text for particular XPath using selenium like if I want to get cost using XPath: productListing[@title=" ABC Products"]/product[1]/cost. how to write that in selenium

```
<span id="_0:preferredLocaleTipTextLbl0"><note>
  <?xml version="1.0"?> 
 <productListing title="ABC Products"> 
  <product> 
    <name>Product One</name> 
    <description>Product One is an exciting new widget that will 
      simplify your life.</description> 
    <cost>$19.95</cost> 
    <shipping>$2.95</shipping> 
  </product> 
  <product> 
    <name>Product Two</name> 
    ... 
  </product> 
  <product> 
    <name>Product Three</name> 
    <description>This is such a terrific widget that you will 
      most certainly want to buy one for your home and another one 
      for your office!</p> 
    <cost>$24.95</cost> 
    <shipping>$0.00</shipping> 
  </product>
```

...

Comment: A validation of a XML file is only possible with a XSD schema. If you want to verify that a specific element has the right value, it might be better to use a different wording.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium does not native support verifying text present in an XML page.
Why not check with language which you’re writing automation script?
If you’re doing automation with Java, you can use [Java XPath Parser](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_xpath_parser.htm)